# Protobufs and Objects Java

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

I am currently implementing a small client server database in Java.

I model transactions using Java Objects. Each transaction contains a number of statements and some metadata. These  are passed from the client to the server and back using sockets and java serialization. They are then operated on in the database (ex: their metadata is updated, etc.)

I have observed that native java serialization iscurrently the bottleneck, I therefore want to move away from it.  Having considered Kryo and manual benchmarking, I think that Protobufs are a good way to replace serialization.

The system now takes Transactions and statements defined as protobuffers.

My question is:  is it more efficient to, upon receipt of a protobuffer on the server side, to create a regular Transaction Object, modify and operate on that, and then populate a new protobuf to send back to the client, or is it preferable to operate directly on the protobuf (the operations I do on the transaction in the server involves updating lists, etc.)

Alternatively, would it be preferable to use Kryo for such a use case ?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand

Comment: Edited to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will find in the long run that having your own business objects that your code mainly works on and keeping the protobufs in the inteface code will work best for you.

This is my experience. Why?

First, you don't end up with any protobuf specifice classes or artifacts in the business objects. That makes it easier to debug when there is a problem in the business code because you can rule out any bugs caused by protobuf code that isn't there. Also, those business classes will not be importing any protobuf stuff which makes things simpler.

Second, the code you use to translate to and from protobufs when doing the in and out transfer becomes a place where little bits of code can convert things. You may want a complex graph of objects on the business side but just a reference on the transfer side. For example, you might have a full customer object attached to an invoice in the business logic. That's handy sometimes. But when transferring out, you may only want to put the customer id (in cases where the other system has customer DB access) or you may want to only put name, phone and zip code for a web facing system that just displays it to a user.

Both of those can be boiled down to better separation of concerns, better isolation of system components and better encapsulation.

Comment: I agree - separation of domain object classes from interfacing / data transfer object classes is a good thing and it doesn't cost much performance for the flexibility you gain.